# Shell script to copy files

Tags: linux, shell, shellexecute

If there exist a directory,

/backup/
 And the files in it are a.gz b.gz c.gz

And another directory /backup-directorybackup 
  And the files in it are a.gz

I need a shells  script to compare two directories if the files are present then ignore it and if the filesare not present copy it to the destination directory

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"rsync" command has it all

Answer (score 2):

`rsync -a /backup/ /backup-directorybackup/`